# Ubuntu offline updates using apt-offline

Tags: apt, updates, versions, offline, apt-offline

1. When I'm installing `apt-offline` using `sudo apt install apt-offline` command it installs apt-offline version 1.8.4-1 (the latest, as I understand)
   When trying to create a signature file using command `sudo apt-offline set ~/offline-data.sig` -  getting error: **ERROR: No option specified to set command**
   If I download and install apt-offline version 1.8.2-1 - all works and file created.
2. Download the update files, according to the sig file. Command: **apt-offline get -d ~/offline-data-dir offline-data.sig**
   • With version 1.8.4-1 - all downloads are "green" and no errors are shown.
   • With version 1.8.2-1 some of files are red with error below:
   **ERROR: Giving up on URL ......**  (The list of files posted below)
   Running with `--verbose` key shows a list of failed files at the end.
   Running version 1.8.4-1 with `--verbose` also shows "Giving up" during download, but they are not marked red and there is no errors at the end.

Questions:

1. How I could start working with apt-offline version 1.8.4-1 without getting **ERROR: No option specified to set command**?
2. Do I need those missing files or may just to ignore the errors?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

```
VERBOSE: The following files failed to be downloaded.
VERBOSE: Not all errors are fatal. For eg. Translation files are not present on all mirrors.
VERBOSE: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/main/binary-all/Packages.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/main/i18n/Translation-en_IL.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/main/dep11/Components-all.yml.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/main/cnf/Commands-all.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/restricted/binary-all/Packages.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_IL.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/restricted/dep11/Components-all.yml.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/restricted/dep11/icons-48x48.tar.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/restricted/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/restricted/cnf/Commands-all.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/universe/binary-all/Packages.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/universe/i18n/Translation-en_IL.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/universe/dep11/Components-all.yml.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/universe/cnf/Commands-all.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/multiverse/binary-all/Packages.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_IL.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/multiverse/dep11/Components-all.yml.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/multiverse/dep11/icons-48x48.tar.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/multiverse/cnf/Commands-all.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/binary-all/Packages.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/i18n/Translation-en_IL.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/dep11/Components-all.yml.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/cnf/Commands-all.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/restricted/binary-all/Packages.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_IL.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/restricted/dep11/Components-all.yml.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/restricted/dep11/icons-48x48.tar.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/restricted/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/restricted/cnf/Commands-all.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/universe/binary-all/Packages.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/universe/i18n/Translation-en_IL.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/universe/dep11/Components-all.yml.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/universe/cnf/Commands-all.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/multiverse/binary-all/Packages.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_IL.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/multiverse/dep11/Components-all.yml.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/multiverse/cnf/Commands-all.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/main/binary-all/Packages.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en_IL.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/main/dep11/Components-all.yml.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/main/cnf/Commands-all.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/restricted/binary-all/Packages.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_IL.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/restricted/dep11/Components-all.yml.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/restricted/dep11/icons-48x48.tar.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/restricted/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/restricted/cnf/Commands-all.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/universe/binary-all/Packages.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-en_IL.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/universe/dep11/Components-all.yml.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/universe/cnf/Commands-all.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/multiverse/binary-all/Packages.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_IL.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/multiverse/dep11/Components-all.yml.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/multiverse/cnf/Commands-all.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/main/binary-all/Packages.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/main/i18n/Translation-en_IL.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/main/dep11/Components-all.yml.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/main/cnf/Commands-all.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/restricted/binary-all/Packages.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_IL.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/restricted/dep11/Components-all.yml.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/restricted/dep11/icons-48x48.tar.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/restricted/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/restricted/cnf/Commands-all.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/universe/binary-all/Packages.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/universe/i18n/Translation-en_IL.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/universe/dep11/Components-all.yml.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/universe/cnf/Commands-all.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/multiverse/binary-all/Packages.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_IL.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/multiverse/dep11/Components-all.yml.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/multiverse/dep11/icons-48x48.tar.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar.lzma failed.
VERBOSE: http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/multiverse/cnf/Commands-all.lzma failed.
```

Comment: You can use apt-offline or apt-offline-gui. https://github.com/rickysarraf/apt-offline/wiki

Answer (score 1):

For the first question I found an answer.
The difference between versions 1.8.2-1 and 1.8.4-1 - 1.8.2-1 after getting command `sudo apt-offline set ~/offline-data.sig` prepares file and 1.8.4-1 requires `--update --upgrade` keys for that action.

So request should look like this: `sudo apt-offline set ~/offline-data.sig --update --upgrade`

More information could be found here: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/apt-offline.8.html